# Ruby on Rails : twitter-bootstrap-rails generate a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi in my rails app im using the twitter-bootstrap framework.
I've generate a controller

```
rails g controller controller_name action1 action2
```

how i can add bootstrap to the views?

Can i use a generator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you installed `gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'` gem.

You just need to run generator `rails generate bootstrap:install static` that will install all related files into your application.

Once you done with this, you can generate your layout and theme, like an example `rails g bootstrap:themed Posts`

You can find more details from [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)

You can view video tutorial from railscasts [Twitter Bootstrap Basics](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics?view=asciicast)

Comment: Yes ok, got it this is for a basic installation of a SCAFFOLD. my answer was a little bit different. If i create a controller this will provide to a creation of views (one for every action that i create with the controller). If i run the command : rails g bootstrap:install static this will provide to assign the stylesheets of bootstrap to my views automatically or i need to run a generator?

Comment: Yes. If you will use bootstrap css classes in your view file, it will automatically assign. Like an example if you want to add navigation menu bar in your application then you can use bootstrap classes like this `<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">` with other classes.